# Oracle SQL query to find all projects where specific user has newest entry

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks in simplified version like this with date values, name, user:

[image]

I would like to have a query that gives me the projects for which a specific user has the newest date. For instance if I look for User U1 it would return A. If I look for User U2 it would return B. It will usually return serveral projects as the table is very long and a user can have the newest date for n projects .

I have been trying for a while now without success. How can I do this?

Comment: And what if the datetime are same for a Project and user?

Comment: The newest project for user U1 is C, isn't it?

Comment: The actual table stores also the time in hours, minutes, seconds, having usually less then 10 entries per Project. Same datetime values would be very rare and one could live with giving one of these users as result.

Comment: Yes Parado the newest project for U1 is C. But when I ask for U1 I want the project where U1 ist newest user which is A since for C user U3 has a newer entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try with to use sub-query as below

```
select * 
from projects P
where P.DateTime = (select max(P1.DateTime)
                  from projects P1
                  where P.User = P1.User 
                 )
and P.User = 'U1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Project FROM
(
SELECT Project, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS Rank
FROM table
)
WHERE Rank = 1
```

If multiple (say 2) rows have the same [DateTime], row_number() will return 1 and 2 as Rank, if you use Rank(), they will both return 1.

Comment: I tried to upvote this, but then you deleted it so I posted my own version.  If you need to account for ties, consider describing the difference between `row_number` and `rank`.

Comment: `[DateTime]` is invalid `[` or `]` is not allowed for an identifier in SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name DateTime is a reserved word.

Comment: No it's not - not in standard SQL and not in Oracle. And if it was, you would need to put it in double quotes, not in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by project order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and user = SELECTEDUSER;
```

If a project can have multiple rows on the maximum date, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Do you mean `Partition By User`?

Comment: @artm . . . No, the question is the most recent user on a project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done with this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USER = 'USERNAME' AND (PROJECT, DAT) in (SELECT PROJECT, MAX(DAT) as MAXDAT FROM TABELLE GROUP BY PROJECT)
```